# openfire mysql UTF-8 encoding fails after restart

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8, openfire

I'm connecting openfire with mysql using jdbc. After setting **characterEncoding=UTF-8** in DB connection URL everything works fine and utf8 data could be written successfully into db. However whenever openfire restarts encoding no longer works, and everything saved into DB becomes "???".

I've googled a lot on this, but everything I found (like [this](http://goo.gl/mQ9TxG) and [this](http://goo.gl/x3Unud)) are mostly tutorial on initial setting, the one I already succeeded. The key of successful initial setting I believe is [1] have utf-8 in your db and [2] use characterEncoding=UTF-8 in your JDBC connection. The problem is it fails AFTER openfire restart, and I couldn't find any solution to this.

If anyone has any slight idea on how to solve this issue please help. I believe I'm not the only one sufferred from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

Turns out it's the escaping problem on serverURL saved in openfire.xml. Apparently the & character is escaped twice and cause the wrong url:

```
<serverURL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avmcdb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</serverURL>
```

Should be

```
<serverURL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avmcdb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</serverURL>
```

After modifying this line and restart openfire, everything works well.